# Plotting values on an ASCI file; how to link values ot cells and turn missing data into NA

Tags: r, raster, matching

I have tried some existing code of a colleague but got totally lost.

In the forest modeling program we're using, we import maps where unavailable or unused cells have a value '0' and from there, each cell with data gets a unique value starting from 1 and increasing to the total number of cells with data.This plots into a raster map in the actual dimensions of our model forest.

I have an ASCI file with the coordinates of the resource units (RUs) and I want to create a crude heat map of the RUs which have a high proportion of pine trees: RUs with a 'low proportion of thick trees get a value of 500 and RUs which exceed a threshold get a value of 1500; my idea was to plot green dots in a yellow or . After filtering the model output for RUs that contain pine trees, "year 0" and replacing all values with either 500 or 1500, I get a following "new_df":

```
  year ru  rid DBH over 15
1    0  4 4635         500
2    0  5 3817         500
3    0  9 3016         500
4    0 10 3435         500
5    0 12 3177         500 (et cetera for about 18000 rows; about 400 of 18000 ru are value '1500')
```

Chatbot and I had a wonderful time today. But I am completely stuck in how to plot "new_df" onto the ASCI map. Obviously, there are missing RUs because of the filtering. I tried to turn missing values in NAs but still the message keeps returning when running the code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

#Read the ASCI file with point coordinates of RUs
ru_index <- raster(paste0(dataroot, "ru_index.asc"))

#Create a function to replace values in the map raster
replace_values <- function(x, new_df) {
  ifelse(x %in% new_df$ru, new_df$`DBH over 15`[match(x, new_df$ru)], NA)
}

#Update the values in the map raster
map <- calc(ru_index, replace_values, df = new_df)


**Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function **
```

Advice on how to fix this and continue from here is much appreciated. I am a beginner in R and really hope for some thoughtful, easy explanation. Many thanks in advance.